# Is there a start deactivated for particles as well as rigidbodies?

Tags: particles

So I'm using the explode modifier and I would like it if the explode particles only fell when hit with an object with collision. Is there an option for start deactivated or a way you can keep particles still until hit?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Not that I would be aware of. What I would do would be to set the particle simulation's starting frame to the frame when your object gets hit.